# CSS: IMG not displaying despite being located in the right place

Tags: html, css

I cannot get the image I want to be displayed on my HTML page. I believe my css links correctly, I also believe my image links correctly. I am unsure if this is a "image not located in the right place" type of issue, or if I am simply not using "background-image: url" correctly.

I just want the image to display on my html page. Please advise.

CSS:

```
 {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;

    }

    header{

    /* why won't this work? */
      background-image: url(img\background.jpg);

      height: 100vh;
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;

    }

    /* header {
        background-color: linen;
    } */

    h1 {
        color: maroon;
        margin-left: 40px;
    }
```

*Directory structure:*
[image]HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
<!-- I have no idea what these do -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Kacie Ahmed</title>

    <!-- Link to my stylesheet -->
    <link href="css/webpage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>


  <body>

    <header>

      <div class="row">
        <ul class="main-nav">
          <li> <a href=""> HOME</li>
            <li> <a href=""> ABOUT ME</li>
              <li> <a href="">EXPERIENCE</li>
                <li> <a href="">SKILLS</li>

        </ul>


    </header>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your directory is incorrect. You need to change your `url()` to be:

`background-image: url('../img/background.jpg');`

The `../` means go out of the css folder, the `img/` means go into the img folder, and the `background.jpg` means use the background.jpg image.

```
 header{
    background-image: url('../img/background.jpg');;
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
 }
```

Also, note that you should use forward slashes (`/`) rather than backslashes (`\`) and your url *should* be wrapped within quotes (as a string)

Answer (score 0):

The Url of your image is not correct, use `/` instead of `\`.

You also forgot the `</div>` close tag for the `<div class="row">`